# How to get rid of zero value in a int slice in Go?

Tags: for-loop, go, slice

I am trying to find even numbers in a list of numbers, here is my attempt:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    nums := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}
    res := []int{}
    for n := range nums {
        if n%2 == 0 {
            res = append(res, n)
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(res)
}
```

It seems straightforward; however, when I run the program, I got the result

```
[0 2 4 6]
```

Where does the zero come from? It must be from the empty slice `res`. How can I get rid of this zero?

Comment: This is covered in the [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/16).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
for n := range nums {
    // ...
}
```

`n` is not the elements of the `nums` slice, it is the **index**. So basically you tested and added the indices of the elements to your `res` result slice.

Instead do this:

```
for _, n := range nums {
    // ...
}
```

With this change, output will be (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/2CNIX95MmRX)):

```
[2 4 6]
```

This is detailed in [Spec: For statements](https://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements), For statements with range clause:

> For each iteration, iteration values are produced as follows if the respective iteration variables are present:
>
> ```
> Range expression                          1st value          2nd value
>
> array or slice  a  [n]E, *[n]E, or []E    index    i  int    a[i]       E
> string          s  string type            index    i  int    see below  rune
> map             m  map[K]V                key      k  K      m[k]       V
> channel         c  chan E, <-chan E       element  e  E
> ```